# jquery preventing selectedindexchanged event on dropdown?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdown, on which i created jquery for multi-select. When i add autopostback=true and selectedindexchanged event, dropdown doesn't fire.

Please suggest me how to get the selectedindexchanged event fired if i am using jquery?

Comment: @DotNetUser....I am using the code for comma separated dropdown and replaced the html control with asp control in the below link... http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

Comment: how to pass value which is in jquery to my aspx page